# How to edit npm config file with visual-studio-code?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, vi

The default editor of `npm` config is `vi`. After read this docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#editor

```sh
☁  nodejs-project  npm get editor
vi
```

Now, I want to edit `npm` config using `visual-studio-code`

So, I set `npm` editor to `visual-studio-code` like this:

```sh
☁  nodejs-project  npm set editor visual-studio-code
☁  nodejs-project  npm get editor
visual-studio-code
```

And, try this command, got an error:

```sh
☁  nodejs-project  npm config edit
npm ERR! path visual-studio-code
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn visual-studio-code
npm ERR! enoent spawn visual-studio-code ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ldu020/.npm/_logs/2019-01-18T03_00_59_872Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check vscode binary:

```sh
☁  nodejs-project  brew cask info visual-studio-code
visual-studio-code: 1.30.2,61122f88f0bf01e2ac16bdb9e1bc4571755f5bd8 (auto_updates)
https://code.visualstudio.com/
/usr/local/Caskroom/visual-studio-code/1.22.2,3aeede733d9a3098f7b4bdc1f66b63b0f48c1ef9 (64B)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/visual-studio-code.rb
==> Names
Microsoft Visual Studio Code
VS Code
==> Artifacts
Visual Studio Code.app (App)
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code (Binary)
```

It should set `npm` editor to `code`, not `visual-studio-code`

```sh
☁  nodejs-project  npm set editor code
☁  nodejs-project  npm get editor
code
```

Now, `npm config edit` will use `vscode` open `.npmrc` file.